# Click events of DOM are not working, while asynchronous function is getting executed inside document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a component to the DOM asynchronously while html page is visible to the users.

But the click event of the page is not working until the component rendering is complete.

I tried to bind click events on some of the buttons/icons on the page, through html onClick binding, JavaScript addEventListner, and jQuery click() function.

None of the above is working until the asynchronous component rendering is complete

```
$('#icon').on('click', function(){
  // icon is already present in the dom
 alert("clicks working");
});

function render_all_commentBox()
{
 //This function will take alot of time to fetch data from server
  var data= { /* having fetched data from server */ };
  var comment =  $("<div/>").addClass("comment-box").append(data[key]);
  $("body").append(comment);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  hideLoader();

  //using setTimeout to render component asynchronously
  setTimeout(function(){  

    render_all_commentBox(); // to fetch and render user's comments from database to html
    //until all the comment boxes are not rendered dom click events not working, once the execution of above function completes the bindings started working.

  }, 20);
});
```

The expected result should click bindings must work if it document is ready, the asynchronous script should be executed parallel while the user is using the web page.

Comment: Hmm ,you should learn more about event loop and event binding.

Comment: So... why not just put the event binding after the `render_all_commentBox()` ?

Comment: @HaoWu I also tried that, It is also causing the same issue.
The render_all_commentBox() function is taking some time to render all the comment boxes, mean while the bindings are not working, once execution of render_all_commentBox() function is completed then the bindings start working.

Comment: @AlivetoDie it won't work unless the dom is rendered with the elements.Thers should be something to bind to

Comment: @Shubh  what i am saying is try like this:  `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#icon' , function(){
     alert("clicks working");
    });
});`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I tried but it is not working again :)

Comment: sounds like your using ajax or similar, you need to execute when ist done... there are handles for this... just look at the API docs.... completed/done/success of the web ajax type call.

Answer (score 1):

try using `.on()` or `.delegate()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#icon', function(){
  // icon is already present in the dom
 alert("clicks working");
});
```

refer below:
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ or 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: NOTE:-  `.delegate()` :- : Deprecated > Deprecated 3.0

Comment: Already Tried, not working for me. Actually this will work when icon is not already there and added late in the dom. But in my case icon is already there click is getting binded, but the click event doesn't work until the asynchronous function is getting rendered, after that click started working

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your js file include after the JQuery library file link and try to bind click inline or
use code like :

```
  $(document).on('click', '.icon', function(){
        alert('xyz');
   });
```

Comment: Already Tried, not working for me.
Actually this will work when icon is not already there and added late in the dom.
But in my case icon is already there click is getting blinded, but the click event doesn't work until the asynchronous function is getting rendered, after that click started working